# libgdx best approach for big list with game objects

Tags: list, optimization, collections, libgdx

I am planning a game, where I will have hundreds of game objects that should be drawn in certain order, and everyone of them will be able to spawn objects that should remain in the position of their parent (if the parent objects is drawn at the middle, they also should be drawn there).

**So I need list that can perform the following operations fast:**
add(), insertAt(pos), remove(pos), get(pos)

I have analyzed some data and have come to the following:

**I will be using the Unordered Array of libgdx for storing the objects**, with:

add() - O(1)

remove(pos) - O(2), because it uses swaping technique and at the end removes the last element

insert(pos) - O(2) for the same reason

get() - O(1)

**I will also be using a LinkedList for keeping the order** with references to the unordered array, so I can add objects in the middle fast.

I want to ask is this the best approach or am I missing something?

Comment: It is the naive approach, but you can also use an entity system like with LibGDX's own "Ashley": https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/wiki/Efficient-Entity-Systems-with-pooling

Comment: Thank you.I will look into that. By the way, I have planned object pooling for the most objects. I have not used any entity systems so far, but it seems interesting.

Comment: I haven't used it either myself (haven't used LibGDX in a while, and Ashley didn't exist when I did), I've just seen that it exists to solve exactly this type of problem :)

Comment: If you have hundreds of game objects all visible on the screen at once, then storing them is probably not the most of your concern (you store them front to back relative to the camera). If they are not visible all at once, then you might want to optimize for (frustum) culling.

Comment: Yes, but then I have runtime objects like bullets spawning constantly and they need to be somewhere in the middle of the list, so I need fast insertion anywhere. I also need to be able to get objects fast from any position!
I've spend all of today looking into Ashley, and I am seriously considering using it!

Comment: Is there an actual problem you're facing (which would be solved by using e.g. ashley), or are you just looking for ways to (over)complicate your code and design? Keep in mind: dont do premature optimizations and dont try to solve problems that don't exist. If an array (I don't think you need a LinkedList) works for you, then just use that. If you do actually want to solve a performance problem then at least make sure that you can actually compare it (measure it), so you are sure that it actually fixes it. Never assume!